# How to color text by character in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I want to color a string, but character by character different. I have one array with the text and one array with values between -1 and 1, where -1 should represent "red" and 1 should be "green". 0 can be white, yellow or a fading color between red and green.

Each character should have its color regarding the scoring.

The data look like this:

```
array([['a', 'c', 'm', 'e', 't', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'e'],
   ['0.1716490432811229', '0.062389299621661884',
    '0.26545182258229466', '-0.07999088246625552',
    '-0.4499291603930515', '-0.7465421931327068', '-0.812006046307664',
    '-0.8443500193245104', '-0.865253671942029','-0.8697487071105282',]],
  dtype='<U32')
```

I was able to generate the colors:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.cm as cm

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)
cmap = cm.RdYlGn
x = 0.3

m = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
#print(m.to_rgba(x))

color = m.to_rgba(ws)
color
```

The result looks like this (it's r,g,b,a):

```
array([[ 0.87435602,  0.94709727,  0.57708574,  1.        ],
       [ 0.9561707 ,  0.98154556,  0.68904268,  1.        ],
       [ 0.83529412,  0.93048827,  0.5349481 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.68627451,  0.86620531,  0.43852364,  1.        ],
       [ 0.46889658,  0.77131872,  0.39577086,  1.        ],
       [ 0.45905421,  0.76701269,  0.39469435,  1.        ],
       [ 0.07597078,  0.54809689,  0.2887351 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.08796617,  0.57024221,  0.30026913,  1.        ],
       (truncated...)
```

The target environment is IPython or JupyterHub. The colored text could be as text(preferred), as image, as HTML or maybe as plotted dataframe/seaborn. But the text should be easily readable and may be 50 up to 100 characters log.

Comment: If you want to add any style information, you need a format to give it that style. HTML is your best bet, but you could also use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) if you're using a terminal that supports it. Plain text has no way to store color information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create HTML output in a Jupyter notebook you may use `display(HTML(<your html here>))`. Colorizing the single letters could be done by defining each within a `<span>` with the respective color.

A solution could look like the following:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

def format_chars(chars,numbers):
    numbers = np.array(numbers).astype(float)
    norm = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)
    cmap = cm.RdYlGn
    colors = cmap(norm(numbers))
    hexcolor = [mcolors.to_hex(c) for c in colors]
    letter = lambda (c,l): "<span style='color:{};'>{}</span>".format(l,c)
    text = " ".join(list(map(letter, zip(chars,hexcolor))))
    text = "<div style='font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;'>" + text + "</div>"
    display(HTML(text))
    return colors

chars = ['a', 'c', 'm', 'e', 't', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'e']
vals = ['0.17', '0.062', '0.26', '-0.0799', '-0.449', 
        '-0.746', '-0.812', '-0.844', '-0.865','-0.87']

col = format_chars(chars,vals)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great. However, what versions do you use? I got an error regarding the lambda function (the parenthesis seems to be removed in Python3 with PEP 3113 -- Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking).
But in Python 2.7 I got the error "'module' object has no attribute 'to_hex'" on line 12 (mcolors.to_hex(c)) .

Comment: If you don't want to have tuples in your lambda: `letter = lambda x: "<span style='color:{};'>{}</span>".format(x[1],x[0])`. I'm using python 2.7. If you get the error `"'module' object has no attribute 'to_hex'" ` it probably means you have some very old matplotlib version installed on that python.